# R plot loop problems with last image

Tags: r, loops, pdf

I've created a script for calculating several model for regression. I made a triple loop to save the results of the model in a list and then I can call whatever I need for plotting etc. I've then created other three loop for plotting my data. Everything seems to work but the last loop of the cycle create a pdf file for the plots it gets hang and corrupted. I can, of course, add dummy data in order to have the correct plot that I need but I cannot understand what it is.
I've tried all the options for graphics.off() and dev.off() but it seems I get something wrong.  my R 3.3.2 version Any help appreciated

## Plot DSC thermograms of isothermal crysallization

```
for (intK in 1:nrow(sample_levels)) #the levels of my sample
{   for (intJ in 1:nrow(conc_levels)) #concentration levels of my samples
    {
    plot(0,0,type='n', xlim=c(0,lim_Max_Time) ,ylim=c(0,lim_Max_exo_up),xlab=expression(paste("Time(s)")),ylab=expression(paste("Heat flow (J/g) -exo up")) ) #create null plot     
    for (intL in 1:nrow(Temperatures_levels))
            {       
            if (!is.null(matrix_Avrami[[intK,intJ,intL]] )) 
            {                       
            data_plot <-matrix_Avrami[[intK,intJ,intL]]  #recall my data from previous part in the script
            Time_p=data_plot[5] #choose the x I need
            Time_p<-as.matrix(Time_p) #to avoid Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
            Heat_flow_exo_up<-data_plot[4] #my y
            Heat_flow_exo_up<-as.matrix(Heat_flow_exo_up) #same as before for avoiding erro
            points(Time_p,Heat_flow_exo_up,pch=intL) #create correctly the plot I need 
            }   
            }
        title(main=paste("Conc",as.character(conc_levels[intJ,]),"% GO",as.character(sample_levels[intK,]), sep = " " ) )
        legend ("topright", paste(as.character(Temperatures_levels[,]),"°C",sep = ""),pch=1:nrow(Temperatures_levels))  
        mypath <- file.path("C:","R","SAVEHERE",paste("Heat_flow_vs_Time", as.character(intK),as.character(intJ),".pdf", sep = ""))
        pdf(file=mypath)    

    } 
    dev.off() 
} #the last plot of the loop correctly visualized in my console
```

Comment: just by looking at the code since I cannot test: you may have to move the "pdf" line before `plot(0,0...)`, and `dev.off()` within the IntJ loop.

Comment: The pdf call was in the wrong position ! thanks for the hint sorry ..so stupid error.